# defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5.6

I'm trying to execute QCamera example on Ubuntu, Qt 5.6.
"The camera service is missing" message observed.

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"
```

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm having the same issue on Kubuntu16.04 with QT 5.7. I have /dev/video0 and VLC is able to stream from the camera.

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have all dependencies installed. They are:

> qtmultimedia5-dev

_

> libqt5multimedia5-plugins

Ex:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins
```

Comment: no, it did. Now the error message is camerabin plugin is missing for gstreamer 1.10. It is a pointer to gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad, which solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the example [code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-camera-cpp.html) it seems the example tries to construct the camera object with default camera. Method `setCamera` is obviously called with camera info which is not valid.

```
    setCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera());
```

You can verify that by changing it to

```
QCameraInfo info = QCameraInfo::defaultCamera();
if (!info.isNull())
{
    setCamera(info);
}
else
{
    qError() << "Default camera not found!";
}
```

It obviously expects the camera to be found from `/dev/video0`. You could check if it exists. If your camera is something like video1 or video2, you could rename it to video0 and try again.

You can also add a debug message to the for-loop in Camera class constructor to see device names of available cameras (and modify the code to select other than default camera).

```
foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, QCameraInfo::availableCameras()) {
{
    qDebug() << cameraInfo.deviceName();
}
```