# How to run Camera on Linux using Qt?

Tags: qt, qtmultimedia

I am running camera on Linux and getting an error that

> defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for -
>   "org.qt-project.qt.camera"

this is my code

```
Camera::Camera(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::Camera)

ui->setupUi(this);
mCamera = new QCamera(this);
recorder = new QMediaRecorder(mCamera,this);
mCameraViewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder(this);
mCameraImageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(mCamera,this);
mLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

mCamera->setViewfinder(mCameraViewfinder);
mLayout->addWidget(mCameraViewfinder);
ui->scrollArea->setLayout(mLayout);
//mCameraViewfinder->show();
mCamera->start();
```

Any help?

**Update:**

the `.pro` setup:

```
QT += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets 
TARGET = Camera 
TEMPLATE = app 
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS 
SOURCES += \ main.cpp \ camera.cpp 
HEADERS += \ camera.h 
FORMS += \ camera.ui
```

Comment: What output you get for `ls -l /dev/video*`

Comment: I am trying to know if you have `/dev/video0` device in your Linux system

Comment: @MohammadKanan I dont know that.Is there any way to check that as I am new to Linux and Qt.

Comment: You can use _command line_ and _list_ command: `ls -l /dev/video*`

Comment: It gives me an error **No such file or directory**

Comment: Have you tested your _camera_ directly from Linux

Comment: Yes Camera is working fine by command **Cheese**

Comment: Which Linux you using, I guess the problem is Qt can't find the backend for the Camera, I have seen the error when using Yocto Qt. Solve it by installing right version gstream and qmultimedia module

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14

Comment: @Ramiz, Is this a virtualbox?

Comment: No its not a virtual box

Comment: In Ubuntu, Webcam raw device is normally found as `/dev/video0` ..

Comment: But as u I told you it gives me an error

Comment: Is it an integrated _webcam_ device or USB camera?

Comment: Its an integrated webcam that is running by cheese command terminal

Comment: Did you reboot after testing with _cheese_ ?

Comment: Yes i did reboot

Comment: In summery and as @Jiu suggested, Qt can't find the cam backend ..

Comment: So any solution for that?

Comment: I can't make out whats the issue. In Ubuntu17/VirtualBox I can see the _raw_ device for integrated webcam.

Comment: Is it possible that the camera backend is stored in a different device file within `/dev` in his case?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650773/qt-camera-example-doesnt-work and btw check the `gstream`.

Comment: I have checked it but still same error **defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.camera"**